# Have Siri tell me when something is ready

Tags: iphone, siri

Is there a way to set a reminder or an event so when that event's time comes the iphone will say something like "your eventA is ready, keep in mind the traffic".  Where that phrase is something i can control?

Answer (score 1):

As of right now SIRI can only be initiated by you. You can tell SIRI to remind you about something and you will get a notification about it but there is now way to have SIRI come on and say anything.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (up to and including iOS 12), you cannot have Siri speak to you based on an event (time/date, notification from app etc.). Only *you* can trigger Siri.

However, you could try a few things that *may* give you an approximation of what you want to do.

1. **Shortcuts**: you could write a Shortcut in the Shortcuts app that has a time delay and then speaks the text you want. You cannot have this shortcut automatically invoked - you will have to trigger it - via your voice or your fingers - yourself.
2. **VoiceOver**: you could enable VoiceOver to speak out your Reminders, Timers or Alarms.